# Can I automate text import wizard for a data connection?

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded an Excel Macro to create a data connection to a CSV.

However, when I run it, I need to manually set the Text Import Wizard. How can I automate the Text Import Wizard, considering that I always choose the same options on it?

**Update**: I had never done a data connection through vba so I have only tried to record the Macro, generating the following code:

`Workbooks("name").Connections.AddFromFile "...\data.csv", True, False`

This creates the data connection but prompts the Text Import Wizard Every time. I want to use it to create an Excel Add-in

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: I would use powerquery and import from file. That way you only need to click refresh. Depends if always same file - otherwise easy to modify to pick up file from folder.

Comment: @newguy: I´ve only tried to record the Macro, you can read more in the update

Comment: @QHarr thanks, I´ve tried to use Power Query but I need this for an Excel Add-In and I cannot use Power Query in vba, or can I?

Comment: yes you can though more complicated  if users not on 2016/+. It is in built for those versions and be directly utilised without any additional instructions.

Comment: @QHarr we are using 2013

Comment: @QHarr thanks, using excel 2016 and the macro recorder gave me the solution

Answer (score 1):

Following @QHarr comment, I'm now using Excel 2016. Using the Macro Recorder I got a long code that gave me the solution

`ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="data", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origen = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""...\data.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=8, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Encabezados promovidos"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Origen, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Tipo cambiado"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Encabezados promovidos" & _
            """,{{""FechaID"", Int64.Type}, {""año"", Int64.Type}, {""mes"", Int64.Type}, {""dia"", Int64.Type}, {""hora"", Int64.Type}, {""Nemo"", type text}, {""MW generados"", type number}, {""Tecnología"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Tipo cambiado"""
        Workbooks(This_workbook).Connections.Add2 "Consulta - data", _
            "Conexión a la consulta 'data' en el libro.", _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Carga Horaria;Extended Properties=" _
            , """data""", 6, True, False`

Sorry for the spanish words.